# Grep just one line, then remove

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'd like to know a command to extract just the value from line 8 of this file, minus the `<string>` and `</string>`, in other words output only `3.2.2`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildVersion</key>
    <string>8</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.2.2</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>399.12</string>
    <key>ProjectName</key>
    <string>ServerApp</string>
    <key>SourceVersion</key>
    <string>399012000000000</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Your suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks, Dan

Comment: Don't make us count, which line is line 8?

Comment: To parse XML, use a proper XML parser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==8,$0=$3' FS='[<>]'
```

Result

```
3.2.2
```

- Set Field Separator to `<` or `>`
- If on line 8, print Field 3

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/#1732454)

Comment: Thanks Steven, this works beautifully and is the most concise. I'll mark this as answered as soon as the ten minutes arrives...

Answer (score 9):

As stated by [Steven Penny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002260/steven-penny) and the link [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/#1732454), to parse XML, a proper xml parser is required, one of them is [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint)

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/plist/dict/string[2]/text()' file.xml
```

or with [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) :

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/plist/dict/string[2]/text()' file.xml
```

or with [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint/blob/master/saxon-lint) :

```
$ saxon-lint --xpath '/plist/dict/string[2]/text()' file.xml
```

**And an even better XPath expression** if you want the version number after `CFBundleShortVersionString` :

```
'//key[text()="CFBundleShortVersionString"]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()'
```

Comment: up-voted for the last expression - value after `CFBundleShortVersionString` :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
xmllint 'myfile'|sed -n '8 s#.*>\([[:digit:].]\{1,\}\)<.*#\1#p'
```

if `3.2.2` is somewhere in the file and it is a unique value you can try sed like

```
xmllint 'myfile'|sed -n 's#.*>\(3.2.2\)<.*#\1#p'
```

Comment: What's the point using xmllint and not `sed -n '8 s#.*>\([[:digit:].]\{1,\}\)<.*#\1#p' file` ? Still sounds weird, but less

Comment: point taken..Nevertheless..you will have the same results. xmllint is user friendly with sed (unlike cat) that is why I like using it..:)

Comment: "unlike cat" for opening xml files..I meant

Comment: @xorg sed takes files as arguments

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` it can be done as below.

```
$ sed -rn '8s#<[a-z]+>([0-9.]+)</[a-z]+>#\1#p' file.xml
3.2.2
```